# When manually using new model(), Is it possible to modify a document before save()ing it, using mongoose update operators?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, document

With mongoose, they very often give documentation in which they create a new document on a model on the spot, and then modify a field and save it, like so:

```
const Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);

const small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
small.size = 'big'
small.save()

// saves doc as {size:'big'}
```

What i want to know is if its possible to use this way of creating a doc and modifying it using mongoose doc methods and operators, for example:

```
small.update({size:'reallyBig'})
small.save()

//i would expect the document to now be saved with size:'reallyBig', but it doesn't seem to work this way
```

This example seems useless, but i want to see if this basic principle is possible because i want to use some mongoose operators for more complex calculations and updates of the document, before it is even saved to the databse.

The problem im having is that this doesnt automatically create an ObjectID for the doc, and `Document.updateOne()` seems to internally use the doc's _Id to find it... but i havent even saved it so im not sure how it's supposed to find it.

I want to be able to use ops like $inc, $count, $addToSet and such, but am i missing something to be able to use these methods to modify the doc before `save()`?

Comment: Would you run `small.update({size:'reallyBig'})` against an existing doc? Meaning, would the command actually look like this: `small.update({_id: 'ID'}, {size:'reallyBig'})` Or do you want to do that on an unsaved doc as in `const small = new Tank({ size: 'small' }); small.update({size:'reallyBig'})`?

Comment: i want to do it on a new unsaved doc, that im not fetching from the DB but rather creating it and building it